# ADT-PLUGIN ISSUE

Tags: android, programming-languages

I installed the adt-plugin for eclipse. I'm using Ubuntu 10.4 and have been stuck on this issue for 2 days now.

1. Select Window > Preferences... to open the Preferences panel (Mac OS X: Eclipse > Preferences).
2. Select Android from the left panel.
3. **For the SDK Location in the main panel, click Browse... and locate your downloaded SDK directory.**

   I cant find the location of the downloaded plugin and have looked in /usr /etc /home everywhere possible, I still can't believe im stuck on something so simple.  Anyone who could point me into the right direction, would help me sooo much.

thnx
hi.im.new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android SDK is a different component from the plugin. You need the SDK to do any Android development at all. The plugin is just a helper for Eclipse. It sound like you haven't got the Android SDK on your system. You can get it from:

[link text](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Pick the starter package first of all then once you have that, you can add more components using the SDK Manager which will come with the starter package.